# Align Spinner Text to left when set background on Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in xml file , width and height set to wrap_content and I set the background to spinner,

[image]

the text is shown in center, If I set width in dp or fill_parent then text is display at left aligned, but I need to left align when spinner width is wrap_content

Comment: You may want to attach 9-patch file and layout.

Comment: please post your xml file

Answer (score 1):

You can use like that
Set your Spinner view like :

```
res/layout/my_spinner_textview.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    public class HelloSpinner extends Activity
    {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array,
    //        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
    //    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_textview);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
      }
  //No other modification needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
android:paddingRight="10dp"
OR
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

Set size as you needed.That will set padding to text of spinner view.

Comment: which size are you talking about ? spinner width and height ?

Comment: I set width and height of spinner to wrap_content, because I set background to spinner

Answer (score 0):

Include this four line in your custom text view to make your spinner text as left aligned.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```